# No conection between back and front when deploying on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm struggling to make this page work.
the deployment on Heroku it's a success for both apps (server and front).
but somehow, my front and back doesn't connect properly
here mi node.js | index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
require('dotenv').config();


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public')); //added to search public folder
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));


mongoose
  .connect((process.env.MONGO_URL), {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true, // just a recomended line if there's an error
    useFindAndModify:true
  })
  .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

//added all
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'ok',
    message: 'Hello! I am working perfecly!(get request)'
  });
});






app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}...`));
```

here the heroku logs --tail

```
d=POST path="/register" host=bloghiv-back.herokuapp.com request_id=90b09eda-548d-45dd-b99c-ae52f2ee046a fwd="200.126.224.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=392 protocol=https
2021-10-25T15:42:28.073784+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.3986ef85.chunk.css" host=bloghiv-back.herokuapp.com request_id=8f306df2-0e35-48df-9367-3f6450c6faa8 fwd="200.126.224.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms 
status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-10-25T15:42:28.071575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.f6840f02.chunk.js.map" host=bloghiv-back.herokuapp.com request_id=72752344-da2c-407f-991e-2596b0074e05 fwd="200.126.224.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=33455 protocol=https
2021-10-25T15:42:28.082929+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.2d16cffa.chunk.js.map" host=bloghiv-back.herokuapp.com request_id=14798d98-e88f-463d-8a51-d0dbe94dc664 fwd="200.126.224.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms 
status=200 bytes=967615 protocol=https
2021-10-25T15:42:28.280289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.3986ef85.chunk.css.map" host=bloghiv-back.herokuapp.com request_id=b63816f2-7554-4294-97c1-b8fde1e5ef82 fwd="200.126.224.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=25377 protocol=https
2021-10-25T15:42:31.301468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/register" host=bloghiv-back.herokuapp.com request_id=a7ed0d2a-d689-4353-b78f-a104ed5d0814 fwd="200.126.224.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=392 protocol=https
```

when I open the back end Heroku deploy I can see my front end perfectly, but I can't register (send post request)
[here's an image attached of my back end console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPpuP.jpg)

edit: added routes/auth.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPass,
    });

    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//LOGIN
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    !user && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");

    const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    !validated && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
    res.status(200).json(others);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

According to your attached image of the console, you are sending post request to /register path
But you did not register /register in your middleware with app.use,
Can you send your ./routes/auth.js file?
Maybe you should post register request to /auth/register path if you have any request handler for path /auth/register in you ./routes/auth.js file.

Comment: i added ./routes/auth.js in the post

Comment: Make sure your are sending data to correct path by changing form action to:

<form action="/auth/register" method="post">...</form>

Answer (score 0):

it's likely that you set up your form as

action=/register method=post

instead of

action=/api/user/register method=post